# Leaflet layerGroup in ListMarkers

Tags: leaflet, layers

I am using the Leaflet [List Markers Plugin](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-list-markers) for showing all features currently visible in the map in a list. Adding a single `L.geoJson` layer is no problem and works fine.

Now I am using multiple layers stored in a `L.layerGroup`. In fact, it's still one dataset, but splitted by the filter-option into multiple layers, merged to one layergroup again.

By adding the `layerGroup` to `ListMarkers`, there is no output:

```
var markerlist = new L.Control.ListMarkers({layer: myLayergroup, itemIcon: "blue-marker.svg"});
```

Output list in my map:

[image]

Does anyone know, whether there is a way to insert a `layerGroup` to `ListMarkers` or a workaround?